# Autocarga de clases PHP

Tags: php, poo

saludos a todos, vengo nuevamente con un problema que tengo con la autocarga de clases con spl_autoload.

Esta es mi clase Autoloader:

```
class Autoloader {
    static public function CargarClases($className) {
        $filename = "../classes/" . str_replace('\\', '/', $className) . ".php";
        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            include($filename);
            if (class_exists($className)) {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
}
spl_autoload_register('Autoloader::CargarClases');
```

Este es un codigo que consegui y me venia funcionando bien, pero cuando cambie el codigo para poder usar ajax e hice un directorio de Controladores me dejo de funcionar, yo hago el include de la clase en mi archivo index.php, pero me ha tocado agregar el include autoloader en los controladores, en cada uno de ellos hago esto:

```
require_once("../classes/Autoloader.php");
```

No se en que estoy fallando, cual es la mejor practica para colocar este archivo y donde incluirlo, estoy un poco perdido con este tema.

Saludos y espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de petición AJAX de las que no te funcionen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo mejor es definir una constante en el index.php así `const APP_DIR = __DIR__;` con esto manejas el path correcto donde quiera que estés. En mi caso lo que he hecho es crear un file extra llamado init.php en este defino la constante APP_DIR y hago el include del autoload.php y de los archivos de funciones que voy a necesitar. Toma en cuenta que el autoloader debe utilizar la constante definida para evitar errores de inclusión.

Mi file init.php es así:

```
<?php

const APP_DIR = __DIR__;

// autoload
require __DIR__ . '/includes/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// functions
require __DIR__ . '/includes/functions/html.php';
require __DIR__ . '/includes/functions/util.php';
// ...
```

Entonces mi file index.php viene siendo asi:

```
<?php

require 'init.php';

// procesar la solicitud
//   detectar el controlador
//   detectar el action (función de la clase controladora que sera llamada
//   instanciar el objeto controlador y ejecutar la función
```

Usar el index.php como único punto de entrada de la aplicaición es una buena practica. Con este enfoque puedes implementarlo y ademas en casos especiales (donde no quieres usar el index.php) puedes simplemente incluir el init.php y ya tienes tu aplicación lista para correr.

Un detalle más. No uses el class_exists dentro del autoload. Para mi viene siendo redundante porque el file ya existe. En todo caso si decides usarlo pasa el segundo parametro en false así: `class_exists($className, false);` con esto indicas a class_exists que no use autolaod.

Espero que te sirva! B-)

Comment: Muuchas gracias, de verdad estaba un poco perdido, ya con eso me funciono usando __DIR__ , tomare en cuenta tu consejo de usar un archivo de constantes.

Comment: Nuevamente gracias